# read system call: When input has more bytes than count argument, excess bytes overflow to shell and get executed as next command

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

I am writing a code to **Implement `tee` command using I/O system calls**. This is an exercise in the book *The Linux Programming Interface* by Michael Kerrisk.

My system is **Ubuntu 16.04**.

I am inexperienced with linux programming.

```
  #include <sys/stat.h>                                                                                                                                                                                             
  #include <fcntl.h>
  #include <unistd.h>
  #include "tlpi_hdr.h"
  
  #define MAX_READ 20
  
  int
  main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
    int fileFd;
    ssize_t numRead;
    char buffer[MAX_READ + 10];
  
    // command example: tee_practice tfile
    if (argc != 2 || strcmp(argv[1], "--help") == 0)
      usageErr("Usage error\nDid you supply the filename?\n");
  
    fileFd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
  
    if (fileFd == -1)
      errExit("open");
  
    if ((numRead = read(STDIN_FILENO, buffer, MAX_READ)) == -1) // HERE bytes overflow to shell and get executed as next command
      errExit("read");
  
    buffer[numRead] = '\0';
  
    if (write(STDOUT_FILENO, buffer, MAX_READ) == -1)
      errExit("write");
  
    if (write(fileFd, buffer, MAX_READ) == -1)
      errExit("write");
  
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
  }
```

On input

> Hi I am writing a few lines

the program writes first 20 bytes (*Hi I am writing a fe*) to file and stdout. The remaining bytes (`w lines`) are executed as next shell command, which I want to prevent from happening.

Where am I going wrong?

---

**EDIT**

Not exactly minimal reproducible example, but it works and includes errExit() and usageErro().

```
#include <sys/stat.h>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#include <sys/types.h>  /* Type definitions used by many programs */
#include <stdio.h>      /* Standard I/O functions */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* Prototypes of commonly used library functions,
                           plus EXIT_SUCCESS and EXIT_FAILURE constants */
#include <unistd.h>     /* Prototypes for many system calls */
#include <errno.h>      /* Declares errno and defines error constants */
#include <string.h>     /* Commonly used string-handling functions */

#define MAX_READ 20

#ifndef ERROR_FUNCTIONS_H
#define ERROR_FUNCTIONS_H


#ifdef __GNUC__

    /* This macro stops 'gcc -Wall' complaining that "control reaches
       end of non-void function" if we use the following functions to
       terminate main() or some other non-void function. */

#define NORETURN __attribute__ ((__noreturn__))
#else
#define NORETURN
#endif

#endif

void errMsg(const char *format, ...);

void errExit(const char *format, ...) NORETURN ;

void usageErr(const char *format, ...) NORETURN ;

typedef enum { FALSE, TRUE } Boolean;

static char *ename[] = {
    /*   0 */ "", 
    /*   1 */ "EPERM", "ENOENT", "ESRCH", "EINTR", "EIO", "ENXIO", 
    /*   7 */ "E2BIG", "ENOEXEC", "EBADF", "ECHILD", 
    /*  11 */ "EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK", "ENOMEM", "EACCES", "EFAULT", 
    /*  15 */ "ENOTBLK", "EBUSY", "EEXIST", "EXDEV", "ENODEV", 
    /*  20 */ "ENOTDIR", "EISDIR", "EINVAL", "ENFILE", "EMFILE", 
    /*  25 */ "ENOTTY", "ETXTBSY", "EFBIG", "ENOSPC", "ESPIPE", 
    /*  30 */ "EROFS", "EMLINK", "EPIPE", "EDOM", "ERANGE", 
    /*  35 */ "EDEADLK/EDEADLOCK", "ENAMETOOLONG", "ENOLCK", "ENOSYS", 
    /*  39 */ "ENOTEMPTY", "ELOOP", "", "ENOMSG", "EIDRM", "ECHRNG", 
    /*  45 */ "EL2NSYNC", "EL3HLT", "EL3RST", "ELNRNG", "EUNATCH", 
    /*  50 */ "ENOCSI", "EL2HLT", "EBADE", "EBADR", "EXFULL", "ENOANO", 
    /*  56 */ "EBADRQC", "EBADSLT", "", "EBFONT", "ENOSTR", "ENODATA", 
    /*  62 */ "ETIME", "ENOSR", "ENONET", "ENOPKG", "EREMOTE", 
    /*  67 */ "ENOLINK", "EADV", "ESRMNT", "ECOMM", "EPROTO", 
    /*  72 */ "EMULTIHOP", "EDOTDOT", "EBADMSG", "EOVERFLOW", 
    /*  76 */ "ENOTUNIQ", "EBADFD", "EREMCHG", "ELIBACC", "ELIBBAD", 
    /*  81 */ "ELIBSCN", "ELIBMAX", "ELIBEXEC", "EILSEQ", "ERESTART", 
    /*  86 */ "ESTRPIPE", "EUSERS", "ENOTSOCK", "EDESTADDRREQ", 
    /*  90 */ "EMSGSIZE", "EPROTOTYPE", "ENOPROTOOPT", 
    /*  93 */ "EPROTONOSUPPORT", "ESOCKTNOSUPPORT", 
    /*  95 */ "EOPNOTSUPP/ENOTSUP", "EPFNOSUPPORT", "EAFNOSUPPORT", 
    /*  98 */ "EADDRINUSE", "EADDRNOTAVAIL", "ENETDOWN", "ENETUNREACH", 
    /* 102 */ "ENETRESET", "ECONNABORTED", "ECONNRESET", "ENOBUFS", 
    /* 106 */ "EISCONN", "ENOTCONN", "ESHUTDOWN", "ETOOMANYREFS", 
    /* 110 */ "ETIMEDOUT", "ECONNREFUSED", "EHOSTDOWN", "EHOSTUNREACH", 
    /* 114 */ "EALREADY", "EINPROGRESS", "ESTALE", "EUCLEAN", 
    /* 118 */ "ENOTNAM", "ENAVAIL", "EISNAM", "EREMOTEIO", "EDQUOT", 
    /* 123 */ "ENOMEDIUM", "EMEDIUMTYPE", "ECANCELED", "ENOKEY", 
    /* 127 */ "EKEYEXPIRED", "EKEYREVOKED", "EKEYREJECTED", 
    /* 130 */ "EOWNERDEAD", "ENOTRECOVERABLE", "ERFKILL", "EHWPOISON"
};

#define MAX_ENAME 133

#ifdef __GNUC__
__attribute__ ((__noreturn__))
#endif

static void
terminate(Boolean useExit3)
{
    char *s;

    /* Dump core if EF_DUMPCORE environment variable is defined and
       is a nonempty string; otherwise call exit(3) or _exit(2),
       depending on the value of 'useExit3'. */

    s = getenv("EF_DUMPCORE");

    if (s != NULL && *s != '\0')
        abort();
    else if (useExit3)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    else
        _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

static void
outputError(Boolean useErr, int err, Boolean flushStdout,
        const char *format, va_list ap)
{
#define BUF_SIZE 500
    char buf[BUF_SIZE], userMsg[BUF_SIZE], errText[BUF_SIZE];

    vsnprintf(userMsg, BUF_SIZE, format, ap);

    if (useErr)
        snprintf(errText, BUF_SIZE, " [%s %s]",
                (err > 0 && err <= MAX_ENAME) ?
                ename[err] : "?UNKNOWN?", strerror(err));
    else
        snprintf(errText, BUF_SIZE, ":");

    snprintf(buf, BUF_SIZE, "ERROR%s %s\n", errText, userMsg);

    if (flushStdout)
        fflush(stdout);       /* Flush any pending stdout */
    fputs(buf, stderr);
    fflush(stderr);           /* In case stderr is not line-buffered */
}

void
usageErr(const char *format, ...)
{
    va_list argList;

    fflush(stdout);           /* Flush any pending stdout */

    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ");
    va_start(argList, format);
    vfprintf(stderr, format, argList);
    va_end(argList);

    fflush(stderr);           /* In case stderr is not line-buffered */
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

void
errExit(const char *format, ...)
{
    va_list argList;

    va_start(argList, format);
    outputError(TRUE, errno, TRUE, format, argList);
    va_end(argList);

    terminate(TRUE);
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int fileFd;
  ssize_t numRead;
  char buffer[MAX_READ + 10];

  if (argc != 2 || strcmp(argv[1], "--help") == 0)
    usageErr("Usage error\nDid you supply the filename?\n");

  fileFd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);

  if (fileFd == -1)
    errExit("open");

  if ((numRead = read(STDIN_FILENO, buffer, MAX_READ)) == -1)
    errExit("read");

  buffer[numRead] = '\0';

  if (write(STDOUT_FILENO, buffer, MAX_READ) == -1)
    errExit("write");

  if (write(fileFd, buffer, MAX_READ) == -1)
    errExit("write");

  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: An opinionated view: what you are doing wrong is trying to do interactive input while learning C.  Start out with non-interactive code.  In other words, instead of typing your input in a terminal, send it to your code via file redirections.  This will encourage better coding habits and avoid confusion like this.

Comment: counterpoint to my above opinionated view: avoiding confusion may not be a good thing.  By being confused, you learn new things.  But only if you dig deep and get to the bottom of the things that cause confusion.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I will try the non-interactive way.

Comment: Can you strip `#include "tlpi_hdr.h"` from the [mcve] and include `errExit()` and `usageErro()` instead, please?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I have included the  minimal reproducible example (see EDIT)

Comment: Side note: calling `strerror(errno)` is generally easier than defining your own `ename[]` array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program only reads 20 bytes. Whatever there is to be read after those 20 bytes, from whatever the program's standard input is connected to, stays there. Be that input from the terminal, a pipe buffer, or a file.

If you used the stdio input functions (`fgets()`, `fread()` etc.) instead,
they would ask the OS for a larger block of data (usually 4096 B with glibc on Linux), so the issue wouldn't come up with such a short input.

To get everything there is, you need to loop, reading everything until EOF and, since you're implementing `tee`, also copy all of it to standard output and the output file.

i.e. something in this direction:

```
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    /* setup ... */
    char buf[1024];
    while(1) {
        int n = read(fd, buf, 1024);
        if (n == 0)
            break; /* EOF */
        if (n == -1) {
            perror("read");
            return 1;
        }
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, n);
        write(outfd, buf, n);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But check for errors on the `write()` calls, too. Also, technically, `write()` may return without writing everything you asked, i.e.  `write(outfd, buf, n)` may write less than the `n` bytes you asked. But the cases where that happens are somewhat rare.

Comment: Will the `tee` command in [this](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/tee.c) source code also overflow to shell, if input if too long to handle?

Comment: @HasloVardos, well, `tee` is supposed to read everything it gets, and that's what the coreutils `tee` does (there's the loop [here](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/tee.c#L231)). And that's what I'm trying to say above, the program in your question doesn't loop, it just reads 20 bytes and exits without reading more. OTOH, if you try something like `echo 'xxx echo hello' | (head -c3; echo '---'; sh )` with GNU tools, `head` reads the first 3 bytes, and sh gets the rest.

Comment: So a good knowledge of how tee command works (or for that matter how any command other command works) is necessary to come up with a good solution for that command?

Comment: @HasloVardos, well, yeah, since you do need to build it from rather small pieces. Though a lot of the standard text utilities read everything, unless mentioned otherwise. The POSIX description of `tee` just says "copy standard input to ...", which is perhaps a bit implicit wrt. that. But e.g. `head` says "stop copying after N lines". Note that in most cases you don't need to think about how much you read from stdin, and even though `head -c` only reads exactly as many bytes as needed, something like `head -n1` happily reads a full buffer. Which is usually enough to catch any line from user.